# When should I use auto-scaling and when to use SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I was studying about DynamoDb where I am stuck on a question for which I can't find any common solution.

My question is: if I have an application with dynamodb as db with initial write capacity of 100 writes per second and there is heavy load during peak hours suppose 300 writes per sec. In order to reduce load on the db which service should I use?

My take says we should go for auto-scaling but somewhere I studied that we can use sqs for making queue for data and kinesis also if order of data is necessary.

Comment: Auto-scaling and SQS are two totally unrelated services. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @Adrian suppose i have a application which stores votes for each user in db but during peak hours, this users are very high and voting speed is high so in that case should i use SQS in front of that applcation or AutoScaling of my DynamoDB?

Comment: That depends on the cost comparison of each option and how much delay is acceptable between when a vote is submitted and when it gets recorded in the database. That's not really a question anyone else can answer for you (it has no "right" answer).

Comment: You should check out DynamoDB On-Demand, which allows you to run DynamoDB without the need to provision capacity.

Answer (score 3):

In the old days, before DynamoDB Auto-Scaling, a common use pattern was:

- The application attempts to write to DynamoDB
- If the request is throttled, the application stores the information in an Amazon SQS queue
- A separate process regularly checks the SQS queue and attempts to write the data to DynamoDB. If successful, it removes the message from SQS

This allowed DynamoDB to be provisioned for *average* workload rather than *peak* workload. However, it has more parts that need to be managed.

These days, DynamoDB can use [adaptive capacity](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/) and [burst capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-throughput-bursting) to handle temporary changes. For larger changes, you can implement [DynamoDB Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AutoScaling.html), which is probably easier to implement than the SQS method.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution depends on the characteristics of your application. Can it tolerate asynchronous database writes? Can it tolerate any throttling on database writes?

If you can handle some throttling from DynamoDB when there’s a sudden increase in traffic, you should use DynamoDB autoscaling.

If throttling is not okay, but asynchronous writes are okay, then you could use SQS in front of DynamoDB to manage bursts in traffic. In this case, you should still have autoscaling enabled to ensure that your queue workers have enough throughout available to them.

If you must have synchronous writes and you can not tolerate any throttling from DynamoDB, you should use DynamoDB’s on demand mode. (However, do note that there can still be throttling if you exceed 1k WCU or 3k RCU for a single partition key.)

Of course cost is also a consideration. Using DynamoDB with autoscaling will be the most cost effective method. I’m not sure how On Demand compares to the cost of using SQS.